# Linux autostart firefox on boot without user login

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

im new on Linux world and i need some help.
Im already spend almost week and no sucess.
I need setup Linux instance ( Centos, Ubuntu or etc.) on GCE( Google compute cloud), install Firefox with Imacros.
On instance boot(reboot) i need run this script

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
firefox imacros://run/?m=script.iim & sleep 2000
killall firefox
killall firefox
sleep 5
done
```

Linux instance must be lightweight . I not need itself login to this instance.

Comment: without user login ? it will be hard

Comment: Since early 2017 you can run Google Chrome in "headless" mode, see the blog post https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: Yes without login.  I want configure Linux vm instance on GCE , make image and run 10-20 instances on same time.  I cant waste time on login.  I need firefox to make job instantly after boot.

Comment: In my situacion Chrome is not stable,  i need firefox

Comment: This has nothing to do with x11 or xorg programming, or arguably with programming in general.

Comment: Sorry but i think this is xorg.  Firefox is gui app.  Need find way and step by step tutorial how autologin user,  autostart x server with x11 dummy monitor and  run script from cronjob after reboot.

Comment: http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.x/2003-07/0373.html This is hardly X11 or xorg (or any kind of) programming. Also try http://askubuntu.com It looks like cron is a bad idea for this task, perhaps use xsession.